# Why can't lvalue references bind to const "forwarding references"?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

"forwarding references" is in quotes because `const`-qualified forwarding references aren't actually forwarding references, but I wanted to make it clear that I am *specifically* referring to function templates.

Take the following test functions (code is duplicated to avoid :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U> void print_types() {
  cout << (is_const_v<remove_reference_t<T>> ? "const " : "")
       << typeid(T).name()
       << (is_rvalue_reference_v<T>   ? " &&"
           : is_lvalue_reference_v<T> ? " &"
                                      : "")
       << ", " << (is_const_v<remove_reference_t<U>> ? "const " : "")
       << typeid(U).name()
       << (is_rvalue_reference_v<U>   ? " &&"
           : is_lvalue_reference_v<U> ? " &"
                                      : "")
       << endl;
}

template <typename T> void print_rvalue_reference(T &&t) {
  print_types<T, decltype(t)>();
}

template <typename T> void print_const_rvalue_reference(const T &&t) {
  print_types<T, decltype(t)>();
}

int main() {
  int i = 1;
  const int j = 1;

  print_rvalue_reference(1); // int, int &&
  print_rvalue_reference(i); // int &, int &
  print_rvalue_reference(j); // const int &, const int &

  print_const_rvalue_reference(1); // int, const int &&
  print_const_rvalue_reference(i); // error
  print_const_rvalue_reference(j); // error
}
```

First, I wanted to note that `print_rvalue_reference(j)` only works because `print_rvalue_reference` never uses `t` in a non-`const` context. If this were not the case, the template instantiation would fail.

I am confused why the last two calls in `main` cause errors during compilation. Reference collapsing allows `using T = int &; const T &&` to become `int &` and `using T = const int &; const T &&` to become `const int &`, which means `print_const_rvalue_reference<int &>(i)` and `print_const_rvalue_reference<const int &>(j)` are valid.

Why does `print_const_rvalue_reference(j)` deduce T to be `int` instead of `const int &` when `print_rvalue_reference(j)` *does* deduce T to be `const int &`? Are (true) forwarding references special-cased to yield `int &` instead of `int` as part of its deduction guide?

Comment: `template <typename T> void print_const_rvalue_reference(const T &&t) ` T is not forwarding/universal reference and can only be bound to an R value

Comment: @doug as stated in my first paragraph, I am aware that `const T &&` is not a forwarding reference. However, the function you mentioned can be bound to an lvalue: `int i; print_const_rvalue_reference<int &>(i);` works, as does `print_const_rvalue_reference<const int &>(i)`.

Comment: `print_const_rvalue_reference(const T && i);` can only be bound to an R value. For instance this will work: `print_const_rvalue_reference(+i);` because the unary operator + makes the expression +i an R value.

Comment: @doug I just gave two examples of the function binding to an lvalue though...

Comment: Highlights a bit of a pet peeve of mine: we often hear that universal/forwarding references work because of reference collapsing. Which is true, but the other point, at least as important, which makes them work is that template argument deduction has its special case rule specifically for a forwarding reference with lvalue argument.

Comment: Your two examples show binding of an lvalue to `<T&>` and `<const T&>` Both are lvalue bindings and OK. `<const T&&>` can only bind to an rvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual forwarding references are indeed special-cased to deduce a reference type. See [[temp.deduct.call]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3):

> If `P` is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of `P`'s type are ignored for type deduction. If `P` is a reference type, the type referred to by `P` is used for type deduction. ... If `P` is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to `A`” is used in place of `A` for type deduction.

Thus, in the case where `P` is `const T&&` (which is not a forwarding reference), it is transformed to `const T` and whether or not the argument is an lvalue doesn't affect the type deduction, since value category is not part of the argument's type. Instead, the deduction process simply attempts to find `T` such that `const T` is the same type as the argument (possibly with additional cv-qualification). In the case of `i` and `j`, this means `T` is deduced as `int` and the argument type is `const int&&`.

But in the special forwarding reference case, while `P` is still transformed from `T&&` to `T`, the fact that it was originally a forwarding reference results in the replacement of an argument type by the corresponding lvalue reference type (if the argument is an lvalue). Thus, in the case of `i`, the transformed argument type is `int&`, and in the case of `j`, it is `const int&`. In both cases, `T` is deduced in such a way as to make it identical to the transformed argument type, which means `T` is deduced as a reference type.